# php data difference giving fatal error

Tags: php

i have one date value coming from database and i want to calculate difference between today date and that database date.

the dates coming from database is

```
2012-06-11 18:20:40
```

i use this code to see values

```
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $result['dt_pub_date'];
```

i have written this code

```
$val=date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ->diff($result['dt_pub_date']);
```

but getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date()` function don't return DateTime object, just return string.

You need to use DateTime object.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$val = $now->diff(new DateTime($result['dt_pub_date']));
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `date()` returns a string; so you can't call `diff()` on it (it's not an object). I guess you are trying to use `DateTime::diff()`. So: create a `DateTime` object on which you can call `diff()`.